# Qt no such slot for method

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am trying to learn Qt (using CMake/c++). Here is piece of code that I wrote. I am trying to use connect functionality. There is no compiling error. I used also following command to re-generate moc file.

***moc -o moc_SimulationRunner.cpp SimulationRunner.h***

However I am still receiving this error while running my project:

**QObject::connect: No such slot SimulationRunner::_OpenFileDialog(file_address)**

my header file is:

```
class SimulationRunner : public QWidget
  {
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    explicit SimulationRunner(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

  private:
    QGroupBox *createFirstExclusiveGroup();

  private slots:
    bool _OpenFileDialog(QLineEdit* i_line_edit, std::string = "");

  };
```

and my cpp file is:

```
QGroupBox *SimulationRunner::createFirstExclusiveGroup()
  {
  QGridLayout *grid = new QGridLayout;
  ....

  QLineEdit *file_address= new QLineEdit();
  file_address->setPlaceholderText("File address");

  QPushButton *file_address_button = new QPushButton("Browse...");
  file_address_button ->setFixedWidth(75);

  grid->addWidget(file_address, 0, 0, 1, 1);
  grid->addWidget(file_address_button , 1, 1, 1, 1);

  group_box->setLayout(grid);

  QObject::connect(file_address_button , SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(_OpenFileDialog(file_address)));
  return group_box;
  }

bool SimulationRunner::_OpenFileDialog(QLineEdit* i_line_edit, std::string /* = "" */)
  {
  if (!i_line_edit)
    return false;

  QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
    this,
    "Open Document",
    QDir::currentPath(),
    "All files (*.*) ;; Document files (*.doc *.rtf);; PNG files (*.png)");

  if (!filename.isNull())
    {
    qDebug() << "selected file path : " << filename.toUtf8();
    }

  i_line_edit->setText(filename);
  return true;
  }
```

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137797/no-such-slot-button-qt?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

The arguments (signature) of the signal and the slot have to match.

If you use the [old string-based Syntax](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) you have to define the arguments in the SIGNAL() and SLOT() macros. So you could connect for example like this:

```
QObject::connect(file_address_button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(_ExampleSlotFunction(bool)));
```

You cannot connect to a slot with more or different arguments. However you can connect to a slot with fewer arguments, e.g. like this:

```
QObject::connect(file_address_button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(_AnotherExampleSlotFunction()));
```

If you use the [new QT5 Syntax](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-3) (which is recommended because it should warn you already when compiling) you don't need to specify the arguments yourself:

```
QObject::connect(file_address_button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &ExampleClass::_ExampleSlotFunction);
QObject::connect(file_address_button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &ExampleClass::_AnotherExampleSlotFunction);
```

---

***QT5 / C++11 workaround***
To pass a different argument, you could connect a lambda function to the signal, in which you call the slot or function. So to pass your `QLineEdit`:

```
QObject::connect(
    file_address_button, &QPushButton::clicked,
    this, [file_address]() { _OpenFileDialog(file_address); }
);
```

Further explanations:
[New Syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)
[Default Arguments](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots-with-default-arguments)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I am still geetting same error: QObject::connect(MatAMX_address_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(_OpenFileDialog(file_address, "")));

Comment: @H'H the signatures (arguments) of slot and signal still don't match. To the QPushButton::clicked() signal (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked), you can only connect slots that take a bool argument or no argument at all.
I updated the answer with a workaround by connecting a lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding the meaning of the argument in the connect.

the *signature* of your slot is

```
OpenFileDialog(QLineEdit*, std::string);
```

and the *signature* of your connect is

```
OpenFileDialog(QLineEdit*)
```

that's why you're getting the warning. You're not calling a function (so it can be resolved with the default parameter), you're *pointing to a function*, so the signature has to be the same.

Tip: unless you have to use Qt4, use the Qt5 connect syntax:

```
QObject::connect(file_address_button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &SimulationRunner::OpenFileDialog);
```

for your specific case:

if you always pass `file_address` in your slot, then just remove the argument from the slot and use it directly in the body.

Otherwise, if you're using Qt4, the only workaround is to make an additional slot with the call with no object.

**Qt4 way:**

```
private slots:
void _dummySlot(){
   _OpenFileDialog(file_address);
}

  QObject::connect(file_address_button , SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(_dummySlot()));
```

Qt5 way, use lambda:

```
    QObject::connect(file_address_button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this](){
        _OpenFileDialog(address_name);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I am still geetting same error: QObject::connect(MatAMX_address_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(_OpenFileDialog(file_address, "")));

Comment: still same error: QObject::connect: No such slot SimulationRunner::_OpenFileDialog(file_address, std::string(""))

Comment: SIGNAL and slots must have the same signature: so _OpenFileDialog should be (). If you need to pass parameters, use a lambda.

Comment: @H'H my bad, you cannot pass parameters inside slot